# Passing URI Parameters to Service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a client and self hosted WEB API Console service like in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync("api/foreman?test1=1&test2=2").Result;
    }
}
```

The foreman controller that the above code is referring too takes data from one database and imports it into a local database.

I am aware that the client can pass parameters via URI like above.

test1=1

test2=2

How do I receive the parameters on the WEB API side and put them into an object/strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a Get method that takes two parameters.  As long as the parameter names match both the request and the method signature, Web API will be able to deserialize the request appropriately.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string test1, string test2)
{
    ...
}
```